# Find a point in a polygon shape

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.3

I have a table that contains a column polygon shape. I need a query that I Want to pass a point(coordinates) if point contains in a polygon_shape of an instance the match will be returns .

```
select * from "DistrictAreas" where ST_Contains(polygon_shape, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(51.3525284 35.6960617)', 4326));
```

this is a error comes from postgresql

> Reason: SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: Operation on mixed SRID geometries
>
> I find that this is the problem :
>   org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBCException: SQL Error: Error parsing
>   SQL data:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Points of LinearRing do
>   not form a closed linestring

Comment: it appears your geometry column is referenced in a different CRS than the passed point (EPSG:4326 / WGS84).

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify what SRID you used to load the polygon data.

Comment: @Vince tnx for your reply . I found this in my polygon_shape column :

Comment: No, invalid topology is a second error, above and beyond non-matching SRID.